# Ubuntu install freezes randomly

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install on an i7 gtx 980 system.

It always freezes somewhere. Sometimes it gets farther than others.

I'm trying to install specifically kubuntu 15.04.

Full Speccy Dump, incase that can help troubleshooting:

```
Operating System
    Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
CPU
    Intel Core i7 5960X @ 3.00GHz   32 °C
    Haswell-E/EP 22nm Technology
RAM
    32.0GB Unknown @ 1199MHz (15-15-15-35)
Motherboard
    EVGA INTERNATIONAL CO.,LTD 131-HE-E995 (SOCKET 0)   37 °C
Graphics
    DELL P2314T (1920x1080@60Hz)
    4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 (EVGA)    34 °C
Storage
    953GB Samsung SSD 850 PRO 1TB (SSD) 41 °C
    953GB Samsung SSD 850 PRO 1TB (SSD) 36 °C
Optical Drives
    TEAC DV-W28SS-B
Audio
    NVIDIA High Definition Audio
```

Comment: Usually seems to freeze while removing packages at the end. Sometimes while configuring hardware

Comment: This last time it froze while trying to restore packages

Comment: Just a thought. One of the many reasons installations can fail or freeze, is usually a hard drive related issue. It can't hurt to go into BIOs, go into the harddrive window, and run a S.M.A.R.T. test.

Comment: Its all new and good hardware, 1TB ssd.

Comment: from which type of media are you trying to install it from? I had weird behaviours with improperly formatted usb sticks. I normally use this: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ and prepare my live usb sticks with windows.

Comment: Ive used 2 diffrent DVDs, and the same usb stick prepared with a few diffrent images using the Universial USB installed from the ubuntu page. Ill try unetbootin, but I doubt thats the problem

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to install by launching the live CD with nomodeset as the video options. I guess it was a graphics driver issue